# Can't find the correct :nth-of-type(n) selector to match matches the element I'm trying to address

Tags: css, css-selectors

http://commerciallynks4.agricharts.com/

I'm trying to hide the background image (the arrow) on the Home menu.

```
.menu div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

And also tried:

```
.menu a:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Neither works and I've started just trying anything but still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menuitem:first-child .menu {
 background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: also you can use :nth-child(1)

Answer (score 1):

Can be:

```
#topmenu .menuitem:first-child > .menu {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the structure more closely

```
tr.menubar_color td:first-child div.menu {
background-image:none;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
table tr:first-child td .menu{background-image:none;}
```

Comment: tried, no luck. still hides all of them. I also tried #menubar table tr:first-child td .menu

Answer (score -1):

```
.menuitem:first-of-type > .menu {
    background-image: none;
}
```